# How to traversed /proc directory in android in APK

Tags: android, apk, proc

I have a apk which sharedUserId is android.uid.system.And I want to traverse the /proc directory to search how many pids in my android phone.

```
        File procFile = new File(PROC_DIR_PATH);//PROC_DIR_PATH = "/proc"
        String[] filenames = procFile.list();
```

but `filenames` lacks of a lot of pids. 
I put the code in system_server and I can  traverse all pid under /proc

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which Android version you are testing your app.

Normally, you should get this information from the Android framework, using getRunningTasks(int); unluckily, from android API 21 on, this method is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)).

Moreover, on newer Android (API 23+) the right to access a lot of different resources inside /proc [has been removed](https://source.android.com/security/enhancements/enhancements60.html) to increase security. Even though I did not tested it, you can probably bypass this by running your app on a rooted device.

Comment: if this is the correct answer, could you please flag it as accepted? thanks in advance!